# Change background of woocommerce /product-category page

Tags: woocommerce, css

I cant seem to find how to change the background of the woocommerce /product-category page. I've changed the archive and single product pages using this css:

```
.woocommerce.post-type-archive-product {
background-image:none !important;
}
.woocommerce.single-product {
    background-image:none !important;

}
```

Which worked fine, but yeah I cant get it to work with the category page.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: which not working?

Answer (score 1):

please try this code in your functions.php

```
if(is_product_category()){
    add_action('wp_head',function(){
     ?>
        <style>
            .woocommerce.post-type-archive-product {
                background-image:none !important;
             }
           .woocommerce.single-product {
               background-image:none !important;  
            }
     </style>
   <?php
   });
}
```

in the above code, I used woocommece's condition tag to determine product category page and then added your CSS to its head section.